# Get all other categories on same level as current category - Magento 2.4.3

Tags: magento2, category, category-tree

We use the following helper to get the current category:

```
class Category extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_registry;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    )
    {        
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getCurrentProduct()
    {        
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }    

}
```

In our template file that works perfect using `$category = $block->getCurrentCategory()` and also to get all child categories `$subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();`

But now we want to also load all categories that are on the same level as the current category. So not the child categories, but the ones that are on the same level.

So how can we get all categories that are on the same level? Seems quit hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use below 2 lines once you have fetched current category

```
$pcategory = $category->getParentCategory();
$subcats = $pcategory->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfect

Comment: Your Welcome, Happy to Help :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

**CustomBlock.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class CustomBlock extends Template
{

    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCurrentCategory()
    {
        return $this->registry->registry('current_category');
    }

    public function getLevelCurrentCategory()
    {
        $childCategories = [];
        if ($this->getCurrentCategory()) {
            if ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategories()) {
                foreach ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getParentCategories() as $parent) {
                    if ($parent->getChildrenCategories()) {
                        foreach ($parent->getChildrenCategories() as $childKey => $childVal) {
                            if ($this->getCurrentCategory()->getLevel() == $childVal->getLevel()) {
                                $childCategories[] = $childVal->getData();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $childCategories;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**categorylist.phtml**

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
$childCat =  $block->getLevelCurrentCategory();
if(count($childCat))
echo "*** Same Categories Name ***<br/><br/>";
foreach ($childCat as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.") ".$value['name']."<br/>";
}
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomBlock" name="product.list.customblock" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::categorylist.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```